# Ventana Flotante - preguntas

Tags: android, tablas, tabla-dinámica

estoy haciendo una app en la que utilizo un drawer y fragmentos y necesito que al dar click en un botón este me genere como una ventana flotante en que me muestre una tabla de dos columnas, la pregunta sería, ¿se puede hacer eso en android? y ¿como lo haría o que herramientas utilizo?
* Les mando la foto para que vean como quiero hacer
ahí les señalo el botón y alli mmismo tiene que salir la ventana flotante con la tabla que al dar clic en un elemento de la tabla este se añada al TextView grande que se encuentra abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estaba pensando en utilizar una clase para que aparezca primero, o no se si usa un RecyclerView pero no se muy bien su función o para que exactamente puedo utilizarlo.

Comment: podes inflar un dialog y pasarle un tablelayout como view

Comment: Hola Gastón, me puedes ayudar en como hacerlo, me urge :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para los que quieran añadir una ventana flotante asi como yo quería y tienen problemas o no saben como hacer aqui les dejo el codigo que utilicé y la explicación.

Bien iré de frente al punto, lo que utilicé en un Pop Up Windows, lo que hace es que a través de un boton nos muestre una ventana emergente flotante (no como un mensaje). Lo que me refiero es que traemos una clase en una pequeña ventana mostrandolo en la misma ventana que tenemos ya (flotante) en a que podemos tener y hacer lo que queremos como si fuera otra ventana "normal" y con tan solo un clic fuera de esta ventana flotante sale y muestra nuestra ventana de fondo que ya teníamos.

Aqui le dejo el código (esto es una prueba):

1.- en nuestro MainActivity hacer un boton y el intent

```
Intent miintento= new Intent ( getApplicationContext (),PopUpTabla.class );
startActivity ( miintento );
```

2.- Hacer una nueva clase (Dentro del OnCreate)

```
 DisplayMetrics dn= new DisplayMetrics ();
 getWindowManager ().getDefaultDisplay ().getMetrics ( dn );

 int width=dn.widthPixels;
 int height=dn.heightPixels;

 getWindow ().setLayout ( (int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.7));

 WindowManager.LayoutParams params= getWindow ().getAttributes ();
 params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
 params.x=0;
 params.y=20;
 getWindow ().setAttributes ( params );
```

aca puedes poner más codigo de lo que quieras mostrar en mi caso yo quise una Tabla)

3.- En el Value/Styles añadir esto (poner tranparente el contorno para poder dar clic afuera y regrese a nuestra ventana principal)

```
 <style name="AppTheme.PopMe">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    </style>
```

4.- Añadir en el Manifest nuestra creacion :

```
<activity android:name=".PopUpTabla"></activity>
```

(exactamente aqui)

```
<activity android:name=".PopUpTabla"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopMe"
            ></activity>
```

5.-Espero te funcione y marcar respuesta como correcta :)